# Using two foreign, auto_increment keys as composite primary key in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the best way to implement this?

I currently have tables, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(table1id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (table1id));

CREATE TABLE table2
(table2id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (table2id));

CREATE TABLE table3
(table1id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
table2id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (table1id, table2id));
```

However, I'm getting errors that two columns cannot both be AUTO_INCREMENT columns. What would be the best way of implementing this, where in table3, table1id and table2id are foreign keys into the original table1 and table2?

Answer (score 2):

`table1id` and `table2id` columns in `table3` don't need to be auto increment at all.  In fact, their values are determined by auto increment columns in other tables.  Instead, just use this definition for `table3`:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    table1id INT NOT NULL,
    table2id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table1id, table2id),
    FOREIGN KEY (table1id) REFERENCES table1 (table1id),
    FOREIGN KEY (table2id) REFERENCES table2 (table2id)
);
```

You *could* also add an auto increment column to `table3`, but you probably won't need it, since the combination of `table1id` and `table2id` should allow you to uniquely address every record in this table.